# Loading the home page on sign in in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's the structure of my app.

```
const App = () => {
    // localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', false);
    // const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
    const isLoggedIn = true;

    if(isLoggedIn === false){
        return <Content/>
    }
    return <Dashboard/>

};
```

If the user is logged in, the `Dashboard` is displayed, otherwise `Content`. This is the structure of `Content`.

```
const Content = (props) => {
    const [isNew, setIsNew] = useState(true);
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            {isNew ? <SignUp setIsNew={setIsNew} /> : <SignIn setIsNew={setIsNew} />}
        </div>
    );
};
export default Content;
```

This conditionally displays either `SignIn` or `SignUp`.
This is the `SignIn` component.

```
class SignIn extends React.Component {
    state={
        email: '',
        password: '',
        isLoggedIn: false
    };
    handleSubmit = async (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem('email', this.state.email);
        const access_token = await getAccessToken(this.state.email, this.state.password);
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', access_token);
        localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', this.state.isLoggedIn);
        console.log(access_token);
    };


    render() {

        return (
            <div className="sign-up">
                <h1>Sign In</h1>
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Form.Group controlId="email">
                        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" value={this.state.email}
                                      onChange={event => this.setState({email: event.target.value})}/>
                        <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                        </Form.Text>
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId="password">
                        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password}
                                      onChange={event => this.setState({password: event.target.value})}/>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                        <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Remember me" value={this.state.isLoggedIn}
                                    onChange={event => this.setState({isLoggedIn: event.target.value})}/>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit" >
                        Sign In
                    </Button>
                    <hr/>
                    <button onClick={() => this.props.setIsNew(true)}>
                        If you don't have an account, Sign Up
                    </button>
                </Form>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to render the `Dashboard` component on successful `SignIn`. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? You seem to already know how to update a parent component's state, so why not apply the same logic to this?

Comment: think you just need isLoggedIn to exist on the state and update it accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a callback function in the props of of `Content` and `SignIn`. When the user signs in, you call the function to let `Content` know and then `Content` in return calls the callback function in its props (supplied by `App`).

Comment: I tried this, but I'm a little stuck, I created an `onSubmit` on `Content` which is passed as props to `SignIn`, but what do I need to pass back to the App to load the Dashboard component?

Comment: There should be an `onSignedIn` (or similar) callback function that you pass to the props of `Content` from `App`. You don't need to pass anything back from `SignIn` or `Content`, just the calling of the function indicates that the user has signed in.
You can then, in `App`, change isLoggedIn to true (which should be part of the state of `App`).

Comment: I can change the state of isLoggedIn, but how do I make the app re-render based on this new state? `useEffect` ?

Comment: The App should re-render by itself once you change the state through setState

Comment: So isLoggedIn should be a state in the App component, right?

Answer (score 1):

Possible way for doing this:

At your `handleSubmit` function, once the user is successfully signed in, we want to change the state -knowing that changing the state makes the component re-render, we want to use that privilege-, thus:

```
    handleSubmit = async (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem('email', this.state.email);
        const access_token = await getAccessToken(this.state.email, this.state.password);
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', access_token);
        localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', this.state.isLoggedIn);
        console.log(access_token);
        // DO THIS BIT::
        this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
    };
```

So, now we now know that the user `isLoggedIn`, the re-render will occur once that happens, and, inside the `render` method, we can make an EARLY RETURN statement that will return the `Dashboard` component instead of the default `SignIn` stuff.

```
 render() {
   const { isLoggedIn } = this.state;

   // our early return!
   if(isLoggedIn) return <Dashboard />

   return ( /* this is the default return you already have */ );

 }
```

Comment: You probably didn't understand the question, I'm not looking at previous login cases, I wanted to render the Dashboard component, when the user signs in for the first time.

Comment: Sorry for the mis-understanding, I believe you haven't implemented  any router in that App is that true?

Comment: Yes, there's no router.

Comment: I updated my answer, I explained as much as possible, let me know how it goes.

Comment: You won't need to bother the App component with the `isLoggedIn` state since you are already looking for the `access_token` in there.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question yet, on SignIn, I want to render the Dashboard component. How can I render the Dashboard without passing state back up to the app. You might wanna read the question once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205098/discussion-between-sultan-h-and-melissa-stewart).